# How to create separate outputs for letters and numbers in the same string and output their ASCII values?

Tags: java, char, hex, ascii

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class testing
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string of any length: "); 
        String convertMe = stdIn.next(); 

System.out.printf("%s%15s%15s%10s%n","Initial","ASCII<char>","ASCII<int>",
"Hex"; 

    for(int x=0; x<convertMe.length(); x++)
    {
       int ascii = (int)convertMe.charAt(x); 
       System.out.printf("%c %30d %13x%n", convertMe.charAt(x),ascii,ascii); 
    }
    System.out.printf("%n"); 
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing!"); 

 }
}
```

Right now the code is outputting all of the ASCII values in one column. I am attempting to split that column into two based on whether the the char is a letter or number. I've been playing around with isDigit but haven't been able to get it to work yet. Since it is a string I need it in my for loop for the post-fix increment to check if true then output in char column if false output in int column would probably work best I just do not understand how to make this work still pretty new to coding.

Edit 1: I forgot to describe the program LOL. The program gets input for a string and prints the string as char, ascii values, and hexidecimal. If the char is a letter print under the column for char and for numbers under int. A space should also read as the ASCII and HEX for space.

Edit2: Was playing around with arraylists and got it to work well but I do not think it is a viable option as it will take the string chars out of order to display them since I have to print in the same statement here is where im at.

```
   public class JMUnit3Ch12
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a string of any length: "); 
String convertMe = stdIn.nextLine(); 
System.out.printf("%s%15s%15s%10s%n","Initial","ASCII<char>", "ASCII<int>", "Hex"); 
ArrayList<Integer>numbers = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer>letters = new ArrayList<>();

for(int x=0; x<convertMe.length(); x++)
  {
      int ascii = (int)convertMe.charAt(x);
      if(ascii<=57 && ascii>=48)
      {
          numbers.add(ascii); 
        }
        else
        {
          letters.add(ascii); 
        }

  //System.out.printf("%c %30d %13x%n", convertMe.charAt(x),ascii,ascii); 

  }

  for(int y :numbers)
  {
  System.out.printf("%c %30d %13x %n",y,y,y); 
}
for(int z: letters)
{
  System.out.printf("%c %15d %28x %n",z,z,z); 
}

  //System.out.println(numbers); 
System.out.printf("%n"); 
System.out.println("Thank you for playing!"); 

  }
}
```

Comment: *I've been playing around with isDigit but haven't been able to get it to work yet*: then post what you tried, tell us what you expect it to do and what it does instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obviously a simple matter of determining which characters within the User input string is either a Alpha character or a Numeric character as you are iterating through the string and then utilize a **printf()** format string to accommodate either or.

To see if a String character is either a Alpha or Numeric character you can use the **[String.matches()](http://www.java67.com/2012/09/java-string-matches-example-regular-expression.html)** method which utilizes [Regular Expressions (RegEx)](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) to make the determination. In the example code below (which is your code modified) we utilize the **\d** expression which basically looks to see if the character (string) we're matching against is numeric. If it is, it produces boolean true and if not it produces boolean false. You will notice in the code below that we've used **\\d** instead of **\d**, this is because the backslash character (\) which is part of the Expression is called an escape character and it too must be escaped when used in a String. So basically, you have to escape the escape character. You'll eventually find the **String.matches()** method to be quite a handy method for specific occasions.

If a character is found to be Alpha then use one format and if it's Numeric then use a different format. Place the desired format into a String variable and then use that variable in your **printf()** method.

Also, I don't know if this is in your IDE as well but your missing the closing parenthesis [ **)** ] within the console output to display the table Header. This **should** create a compile error.

This:

```
System.out.printf("%s%15s%15s%10s%n","Initial","ASCII<char>","ASCII<int>","Hex";
```

Should be:

```
System.out.printf("%s%15s%15s%10s%n","Initial","ASCII<char>","ASCII<int>","Hex");
```

In any case:

```
Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a string of any length: "); 
// Read the input string as a complete line
String convertMe = stdIn.nextLine(); 

// Establish a Header in console display
System.out.printf("%s%15s%15s%10s%n", "Initial", "ASCII<char>", "ASCII<int>", "Hex");
// Create a header underline in console display
System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(29, "\u2500")));

String displayFormat;
for(int x = 0; x < convertMe.length(); x++) {
    String c = Character.toString(convertMe.charAt(x));
    // Create a display format to accomodate whether
    // or not the character is alpha or numeric.
    // Is the character numeric?
    if (c.matches("\\d")) {
        displayFormat = "%4c %28d %13x %n";
    }
    // Nope..it's a alpha character
    else {
        displayFormat = "%4c %13d %28x %n";
    }
    int ascii = c.charAt(0); 
    System.out.printf(displayFormat, convertMe.charAt(x), ascii, ascii); 
}
System.out.printf("%n"); 
System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
```

Comment: I get a compile error for Collections cannot find symbol.**nevermind I can be a little slow sometimes.